# How do I get a full stack trace instead of "Unexpected error while processing request" in Rails test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

When starting my rails server in test environment (`rails s -e test`), something is rescuing exceptions and outputs instead "Unexpected error while processing request: ...error here...". I get the backtrace in development mode.

Who is it, and how can I disable that? I need the full backtrace, not just the error that was raised!

I'm using Rails 3.2.3, Ruby 1.9.3, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

Comment: Did you uncomment the line in `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb`? (Posted as comment since I haven't mucked with 3.2 yet.)

Comment: No, but I just tried to uncomment the remove_silencers! and no change.

Comment: Do you have `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` in your `test.rb`?

Comment: Yes, `consider_all_requests_local` is set to true in `environment/test.rb`

Answer (score 4):

Setting `config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true` in `test.rb` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

Read `env.rb` created by Cucumber:

```
# By default, any exception happening in your Rails application will bubble up
# to Cucumber so that your scenario will fail. This is a different from how 
# your application behaves in the production environment, where an error page will 
# be rendered instead.
...
# 1) Tag your scenario (or feature) with @allow-rescue
# 2) Set the value below to true. Beware that doing this globally is not
# recommended as it will mask a lot of errors for you!
```

Summary:

```
@allow-rescue
Feature: blah blah blah
```

Will make the trick.